# Parent div needs to be overlaped on child div

Tags: html, css, z-index, positioning

I have a div and table which looks like this

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>mydata</td>
            <td>mydata2</td>
            <td>mydata3</td>
            <td>mydata4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

what I want is the div "mydiv" should overlap the table. I've tried all the ways(z-index, positioning) to do this but I am unable to do so. Appreciate for an early response. Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by overlap? can you please share the output you are geting

Comment: @user3523805 do u want to hide table constant ??

Comment: @RRR: overlap means I want to put the table inside the div, and suppose whenever the user clicks on the table, it should actually click on the div, got my point ?

Comment: @Iqbal Pasha : Exactly I want to hide the table behind the div

Comment: @SiddharthaAgrawal it doesnt matter whether parent overlaps child or something.. just add click event to mydiv and since table is inside mydiv. mydiv's click event will fire even when user clicks on table... here is a demo jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aj0xmvvd/

Comment: @RRR: Your code works, but I'm capturing the target element, and when I click on table, it shows "[object HTMLTableCellElement]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting this CSS to `mydiv`. Added an image for your understanding that the `div` is overlapping the `table`.

```
#mydiv
{
  background-color:#666666;
  z-index: 30001; 
  opacity: .6; 
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  position: fixed;
  height:20%;
}
```

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.onclick = function (e) {
  alert(e.target);
}
```

```css
#mydiv
{
  background-color:#666666;
  z-index: 30001; 
  opacity: .6; 
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  position: fixed;
  height:20%;
}
```

```html
<body >
<div id='mydiv'>
    <p style="position: absolute; left:30%; color: White;pointer-events: none;"> 
        <img id="loading"   alt="Loading ..." src="~/Images/loading.gif" /> 
    </p> 
    <table style="pointer-events: none;">
        <tr>
            <td>mydata</td>
            <td>mydata2</td>
            <td>mydata3</td>
            <td>mydata4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
  </body>
```

**EDIT:**

For this you can put `pointer-events: none;` to your table and when you click on the `table cells`, the `div` will get clicked. I have modified the code accordingly.
Hope this helps :)

Do it like this :

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.onclick = function (e) {
  alert(e.target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I want it is  I want to put the table inside the div, and suppose whenever the user clicks on the table, it should actually click on the div, got my point ? Its just like an apple placed inside a transparent box, whenever we want to touch the apple, we actually touch the transparent glass sheet. In your code, we can touch and access the insider table

Comment: Thanks again for your response, will you please answer the whole code in plain javascript please, thanks !

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: by the way... what this statement      document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]   does ?

Comment: it gets the whole body element into the variable `x`, so that we can attach the click event to it. Just like `click` event of `body`

Comment: Alright... thanks for your help, really appreciate it a lot, your solution has been accepted. :)

Comment: thnks @SiddharthaAgrawal :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#mydiv').children().each(function(i, c) {
    disableSelection(c);
});

function disableSelection(target) {
    console.debug(target);

    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined")             // For IE
        target.onselectstart = function() { return false };
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined")  // For Firefox
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
    else                                                        // All other routes (Opera, etc.).
        target.onmousedown = function() { return false };

    target.style.cursor = "default";
}


$( "#mydiv" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).html();
  alert(htmlString);
});
```

```css
#mydiv{
  background : gray;
  position : absolute;
  margin :10px;
  padding:10px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: .6; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>mydata</td>
            <td>mydata2</td>
            <td>mydata3</td>
            <td>mydata4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No Iqbal, this is not what I really wanted, the table content should always displayed but not able to be captured, only the outer div should be captured. Your code is magnificent but not as per my requirements, please help me

Comment: let me make you more clearer, suppose when we click on inspect element on the table, then we should not be able to inspect table and its elements, only the outer div should be selected/inspected/captured... get it this time ?

Comment: thanks Iqbal Pasha for your answer, I do appreciate you for your time, seeking the same help from your side in future too..